# java gson fromjson returns null with non-generic type

Tags: java, json, gson

i've seen that this topic was discussed before, but i havent seen anyone with my characteristics. the title describes what is going on with me. two things, i have go through (i like to think) all the possible answers here, that's why im writing my own question. second thing, the deserialization works perfect in another project and i copied just as it is (maybe that's the problem). i also checked https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-a-Deserializer but i can't find what's wrong with my code. so here is what i have so far:
JSON:

```
{"offset":0,
"total":137,
"per-page":20,
"events":[
    {"id":286560,
    "name":"Arsenal vs Everton",
    "start":"2015-03-01T14:10:00.000Z",
    "status":"open",
    "sport-id":15,
    "category-id":[158208],
    "in-running-flag":true,
    "allow-live-betting":true,
    "market-ids":[1119280,1121697,1121698,1119271,1119299,1119587,1119288,1118302,1120869,1120870,1121696,1121900,1120868],
    "meta-tags":[
        {"id":402,
        "name":"Live Betting",
        "type":"COMPETITION"
        },
        {"id":19,
        "name":"England",
        "type":"COUNTRY"
        },
        {"id":32,
        "name":"Premier League",
        "type":"COMPETITION"
        },
        {"id":2285,
        "name":"March 1st 2015",
        "type":"DATE"
        },
        {"id":1,
        "name":"Sport",
        "type":"Root"
        },
        {"id":4,
        "name":"Soccer",
        "type":"SPORT"
        }]
    },
    {"id":286960,
    "name":"Norwich vs Ipswich Town",
    "start":"2015-03-01T14:10:00.000Z",
    "status":"open",
    "sport-id":15,
    "category-id":[158307],
    "in-running-flag":true,
    "allow-live-betting":true,
    "market-ids":[1121701,1121702,1122048,1120062,1120099,1121700,1120050,1120111,1120087,1121620],
    "meta-tags":[
        {"id":402,
        "name":"Live Betting",
        "type":"COMPETITION"
        },
        {"id":33,
        "name":"Championship",
        "type":"COMPETITION"
        },
        {"id":19,
        "name":"England",
        "type":"COUNTRY"
        },
        {"id":2285,
        "name":"March 1st 2015",
        "type":"DATE"
        },
        {"id":1,
        "name":"Sport",
        "type":"Root"
        },
        {"id":4,
        "name":"Soccer",
        "type":"SPORT"}]}
]}
```

the class:

```
public class Event {

private String id;
private String name;
private Date start;
private String status;
private String sportId;
private ArrayList<String> categoryId;
private boolean inRunningFlag;
private boolean allowLiveBetting;
private ArrayList<String> marketIds;
private List<MetaTags> metaTags;

public String getId(){
    return id;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public Date getStartDate(){
    return start;
}

public String getStatus(){
    return status;
}

public String getSportId(){
    return sportId;
}

public ArrayList<String> getCategoryId(){
    return categoryId;
}

public boolean getInRunningFlag(){
    return inRunningFlag;
}

public boolean getAllowLiveBetting(){
    return allowLiveBetting;
}

public ArrayList<String> getMarketIds(){
    return marketIds;
}

public List<MetaTags> getMetaTags(){
    return metaTags;
}

public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public void setStartDate(Date start){
    this.start = start;
}

public void setStatus(String status){
    this.status = status;
}

public void setSportId(String sportId){
    this.sportId = sportId;
}

public void setCategoryId(ArrayList<String> categoryId){
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public void setInRunningFlag(boolean inRunningFlag){
    this.inRunningFlag = inRunningFlag;
}

public void setAllowLiveBetting(boolean allowLiveBetting){
    this.allowLiveBetting = allowLiveBetting;
}

public void setMarketIds(ArrayList<String> marketIds){
    this.marketIds = marketIds;
}

public void setMetaTags(List<MetaTags> metaTags){
    this.metaTags = metaTags;
}}
```

and:

```
public class EventContainer extends Container{

private List<Event> result;

public List<Event> getResult(){
    return result;
}

public void setResult(List<Event> result){
    this.result = result;
}}
```

and finally the process to convert from json to the object

```
public List<Event> listEvents (String sessionToken) throws APIException{
    String result = getInstance().makeRequest(MatchBookApiCalls.LISTEVENTS.getApiCallName(), MatchBookApiCalls.LISTEVENTS.getURLSuffix(), sessionToken);

    EventContainer container = JsonConverter.convertFromJson(result, EventContainer.class);

    if(container.getError() != null)
        throw container.getError().getData().getAPIException();

    return container.getResult();
}
```

and the the last:

```
public class JsonConverter {

/**
 * We needed to override the adapter for the Date class so to make all dates to be serialized in ISO8601 UTC
 * Just formatting the string to the ISO format does not adjust by the timezone on the Date instance during serialization.
 */
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new ISO8601DateTypeAdapter()).create();

/** This method deserializes the specified Json into an object of the specified class.
 *
 */
public static  <T> T convertFromJson(String toConvert,  Class<T>  clazz){
    return gson.fromJson(toConvert, clazz); // this is failing horribly
}

/** This method deserializes the specified Json into an object of the specified Type.
 *
 */
public static  <T> T convertFromJson(String toConvert,  Type  typeOfT){
    return gson.fromJson(toConvert, typeOfT);
}

/**
 * This method serializes the specified object into its equivalent Json representation.
 */
public static String convertToJson(Object toConvert){
    return gson.toJson(toConvert);

}}
```

i've been battling with this for two days, so maybe my brain is a bit burnt and the answer is so stupid i will smash my head on the wall, but i just cant see it. oh! the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MatchBookApiJsonOperations.listEvents(MatchBookApiJsonOperations.java:46)
at MatchBookPlaceBet.getEvents(MatchBookPlaceBet.java:27)
at MatchBookConnection.testingEntities(MatchBookConnection.java:160)
at MatchBookMain.main(MatchBookMain.java:36)
```

thanks in advance for any help

the container:

```
public class Container {

private Error error;
private String json;

public Error getError(){
return error;
}

public String getJson(){
return json;
}

public void setError(Error error){
this.error = error;
}

public void setJson(String json){
this.json = json;
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly comes back as `null`? Post the code of `Container`.

Comment: in the method listEvents, the convertion from json (third line) comes back as null.

Comment: What version of Gson are you using?

Comment: Regardless of the version, you JSON doesn't match your `EventContainer` POJO at all. However, I still can't reproduce a `null` return value from `Gson`. Please post a complete, but minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: i know what you mean, and i thought that was the problem, so i changed it to match exactly the json, but didn't work either...

Comment: ok, to reproduce the error i have to post the whole thing (which i have no problem, except for the user and password, which i can't), but are many files... tell me what are the alternatives...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: im on it, give me a couple of minutes since it's quite complex...

Answer (score 0):

ok, sorted... my good friend J told me to change the name of the event list to "events" instead of "result" in the EventContainer class (i guess to match the json object "events"), and voila!!!! it works!!! tbh i didn't know it had to match the name, i thought that was something more generic or descriptive, but would never condition whether it parses it correctly or not... well sometimes you have to learn the hard way. Cheers for the rest for the interest and will to help!!